# How can i get a value of textbox located in one control into another control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 Controls - ProductInfo and Distribution.
On the Product Info Controls there are these text boxs - txtPrice, txtDate, txtFreq
On the Distribution control, i would like to get the value of above text boxes. 
I tried :

```
BasePage.FindControl("txtPrice")
```

But it return null.
Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create properties in the ProductInfo control to expose the value of txtPrice, like this:

```
public decimal Price
{
    get { return Decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text); }
}
```

And then in the other user control, try something like this:

```
ProductInfo prod = Page.FindControl("OtherUserControl") as ProductInfo;
if (prod != null)
{
    decimal price = prod.Price;
}
```

**Recursive method**

You may need to use recursion to find the `ProductInfo` control, and if you do something like this should work:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(string controlID, Control parentCtrl)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parentCtrl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.ID == controlID)
            return ctrl;
        FindControlRecursive(controlID, ctrl);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using `FindControlRecursive`:

```
ProductInfo prod = FindControlRecursive("OtherUserControl", Page) as ProductInfo;
if (prod != null)
{
    decimal price = prod.Price;
}
```